# Hide CSS class only in single post pages

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to hide some elements in my posts pages, but not in all the other normal pages. Now they appear in all my Wordpress site (single post, page, etc).

How can I hide by CSS an element? This element has a single class `<div class="frame-content"`.

Can I do something like: `if <post> then .frame-content{display:none;}`?

Comment: add css style in your style sheet .single .frame-content {display: none;}

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php if( is_single() ) : ?>
<style id="my-internal-css">
    .frame-content {
       display: none !important;
    }
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```